# How Route a subfolder to another EC2 instance?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, amazon-route53

I do have a EC2 instance that holds an application and a wordpress blog.

the app is on the root url (http://www.example.com) . And we do have a blog that is on a blog directory (http://www.example.com/blog)

For commercial reasons we must separate the blog to another EC2 server. but we cannot change the blog url due all SEO work done until now.

Important: Those 2 instances should be in different regions and we rather not to pay for inter region data transfer costs. So I don't want to make a proxy using one EC2 to another.

I searched without success how to do it. Is that possible on AWS?

Comment: Put something like CloudFront in front of it, with two custom origins. That said, there are false assumptions in play here. Yes, you can change the blog URL - proper use of 301 redirects will retain the SEO benefits you've already accrued.

Comment: 301 redirects will split page ranking in two. One for the original source and other for redirects. What we want is to concentrate everything in the same url

Comment: You'd be better of load balancing between the two servers, with both apps on both. CloudFront is the only way you might avoid paying inter region fees. Easy way, that you'd pay those fees on, is Nginx or HAProxy on the main box. Seems odd to need them in different regions, what's the point of that?

Comment: The main reason is pricing. I would like to put blog in the us(Virginia) for low costs, and keep the application on the South America for.low latency. Unfortunately South America pricing is too high. And 90% of our traffic is to the blog.

Comment: In addition to the potential transport savings I mentioned [here](https://serverfault.com/a/892589/153161), CloudFront does allow you to split traffic across origins or even regions, based on path patterns.  It is very unlikely to make your costs any higher, and much more likely to lower them.